# tryCatch() Vs if else

Tags: r

I have recently started exploring R programming and have a very trivial doubt. I want to write a function which would try to load the required packages and install the same in case its not installed already.

I have written it using if else logic. My question is will it be more efficient if I use tryCatch()? Is there any other advantage than the ability to handle errors as it is not important to handle errors in this context.

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
Inst.Pkgs=function(){

  if (!require(tm)) 
    {install.packages("tm")
    require(tm)}

   if (!require(SnowballC)) 
    {install.packages("SnowballC")
     require(SnowballC)}

  if (!require(wordcloud)) 
    {install.packages("wordcloud")
    require(wordcloud)}

  if (!require(RWeka)) 
    {install.packages("RWeka")
    require(RWeka)}

  if (!require(qdap)) 
    {install.packages("qdap") 
    require(qdap)}

  if (!require(timeDate)) 
    {install.packages("timeDate") 
    require(timeDate)}

  if (!require(googleVis)) 
  {install.packages("googleVis") 
    require(googleVis)}

  if (!require(rCharts)) 
  { 
    if (!require(downloader)) 
    {install.packages("downloader") 
      require(downloader)}

    download("https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/archive/master.tar.gz", "rCharts.tar.gz")
    install.packages("rCharts.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
    require(rCharts)
  }

}
```

Comment: `tryCatch` *is* used for handling errors, so if you don't need to handle errors, then you do not use this function...

Comment: You should not repeat the same statement so frequently. This is error-prone and generally considered as bad practice (known as the DRY principle).

Comment: @RHertel...I agree...should have used a loop instead.

Comment: You may want to explore the `p_load` function in the **pacman** package

Answer (score 5):

You can check at once and install missing packages.

```
# Definition of function out, the opposite of in
"%out%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) == 0

# Storing target packages
pkgs <- c("tm", "SnowballC", "wordcloud", "RWeka", "qdap",
          "timeDate", "googleVis")

# Finding which target packages are already installed using
# function installed.packages(). Names of packages are stored
# in the first column
idx <- pkgs %out% as.vector(installed.packages()[,1])

# Installing missing target packages
install.packages(pkgs[idx])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I think I will use this with some edits. Actually install.packages(pkgs[idx]) is installing all the packages even when they are installed already.

Comment: I don't know, but match function is returning indexes of the vector as.vector(installed.packages()[,1] and those indexes are not available in pkgs. I just changed the last statement install.packages(pkgs[idx]) to install.packages(na.exclude(pkgs[pkgs!=as.vector(installed.packages()[,1][idx])])). It seems to be working for now. Please let me know what you think or if I am getting the whole thing wrong.

Comment: I have all the packages in `pkgs` already installed on my computer. When I run `idx <- pkgs %out% as.vector(installed.packages()[,1])`, I only get `FALSE`, because all the packges are already installed. Nothing is re-installed.

Comment: Its working :)...thanks once again...dont know what went wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

We can in fact use `tryCatch` for this. If the program tries to load a library that is not installed, it will throw an error - an error that can be caught and resolved with a function called by `tryCatch()`.

Here's how I would do it:

```
needed_libs <- c("tm", "SnowballC", "wordcloud", "RWeka", "qdap", "timeDate", "googleVis")
install_missing <- function(lib){install.packages(lib,repos="https://cran.r-project.org/", dependencies = TRUE); library(lib, character.only = TRUE)}
for (lib in needed_libs) tryCatch(library(lib, character.only=TRUE), error = function(e) install_missing(lib))
```

This will install the missing packages *and load* the required libraries, as requested in the OP.

Comment: I wouldn't use `tryCatch` for this, but rather for errors from `install.packages`.

Comment: @Roland `tryCatch` can handle all sorts of errors, including those which occur if one tries to load a library that is not installed. I don't see any downside in using it in this context.